# Does OpenMP atomic apply to line, to variable name or to actual memory address?

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp, atomic

The way I understand the explanations on the web about the OpenMP `atomic` directive in C++ is that they apply to specific memory locations, designated by some variable (or its pointer?). So when I access this location on different lines of code within a parallelized `for`-loop, can I protect all of them or will `atomic` only protect one line of code and not look at other possible lines that access the same memory location?

For example, consider the following piece of code:

```
int N = 10000;  // just some big number
float a[N];     // a big array
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
    #pragma omp atomic
    a[i-1] += 0.5f;
    #pragma omp atomic
    a[i]   += 1.0f;
    #pragma omp atomic
    a[i+1] += 0.5f;
}
```

In every loop iteration, the same array is accessed at three points, at index `i`, `i` minus one and `i` plus one. In different threads, however, the `i-1` line may evaluate to the same number as either the `i` or `i+1` line. For instance when in thread 1 `i==1` and in thread 2 `i==3` the third (in thread 1) and first (in thread 2) array access lines will access the same array element, possibly at the same time.

Will `atomic` protect these different lines if they happen to access the same memory location? Or does it only apply to one line and would the only solution be to incorporate all three accesses into one line (e.g. by putting `i-1`, `i` and `i+1` in a second array and making a second `for`-loop that loops over them)?

Comment: You're filling a float array but adding doubles.  That won't work.  As long as you use the same data type then it's fine.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OpenMP standard 3.1 (section 2.8.5):

> The **atomic** construct ensures that a specific storage location is
>   accessed atomically, rather than exposing it to the possibility of
>   multiple, simultaneous reading and writing threads that may result in
>   indeterminate values.

So, to give you a brief answer to:

*Will `atomic` protect these different lines if they happen to access the same memory location?*

Yes, it will.

But let me elaborate a bit more. According to the standard, the syntax of the construct is the following:

```
#pragma omp atomic new-line 
   expression-stmt
```

where `expression-stmt` has the form:

```
x binop= expr
x++
++x
x--
--x
```

Of course you have a few restrictions:

1. `x` must be an lvalue expression with scalar type
2. `expr` is an expression with scalar type, and it does not reference the object designated by `x`
3. `binop` is not an overloaded operator and is one of `+, *, -, /, &, ^, |, <<, or >>`
4. all atomic references to the storage location `x` throughout the program are required to have a compatible type

All these constraints **are fulfilled** by your snippet. In particular, point 4 is of no concern, as `x` is always a float in your code (in other words `a[i]` always returns a float). The usual example it is given to show a violation of point 4 is the use of a `union`, as in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fhhcxk3.aspx) posted in other answers.

Comment: point 4 is NOT fulfilled in his snippet.  I know for a fact because I tested it myself.  Try it in Visual Studio 2012 and see for yourself.  He's adding doubles to floats.  If you change the constants to floats it works fine.

Comment: Actually x is always a float but there must be another condition (point 5) that expr be of the same type as x.

Comment: Fine, but that does not change the fact that his code fails in Visual Studio's implementation of OpenMP.  I have not tested it on GCC.  So either Visual Studio breaks the standard or one of us does not understand the necessary conditions.

Comment: Possibly, the confusion is caused by what "compatible type" means. [This document may be useful](http://www.cs.wfu.edu/~turketwh/CSC231/Spring2011/lectures/Lecture22BindingsToPost.pdf). It explains the different types of type compatibility and that C++ uses the stricter type (name type compatibility), whereas C is more lenient. However, when I compile the code with g++ as C++ without the added `f`s, it still runs fine. So there's three options: either the linked document contains false information, or I don't understand it correctly, or g++ (not MSVS) breaks name type compatibility standards.

Comment: Strictly speaking conversion from double to float is not implicitly permitted in C++ (and this definitely makes sense). Anyhow when it comes to literal the compiler is usually smart/compliant enough to understand if a double literal can be represented as a float (or at least `gcc` is). The point is that an error on the right hand side has nothing to do with OpenMP  `atomic`: it is just a C++ error.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
My first try at this failed in Visual Studio 2012.  But I could not think of any reason it should not work.  I changed the constants to be float instead of double (0.5f instead of 0.5).  Now it works.  So to answer your question you can use the atomic the way you did as long as you use the same data type (don't mix float and double).  I learned this readying here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fhhcxk3.aspx (All atomic references to the storage location x throughout the program are required to have a compatible type.)

```
void foo_v1(float *a, const int N) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
        #pragma omp atomic
        a[i-1] += 0.5f;
        #pragma omp atomic
        a[i] += 1.0f;
        #pragma omp atomic
        a[i+1] += 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Below is my original answer before I realized your code was mixing types.  It's a better solution anyway :-)

No, that's not going to work (see my correction above).  You can check these things yourself by generating results with and without OpenMP and comparing and you will see it fails (see my correction above).  You should make a table to see what's going on

```
          a[0]   a[1]   a[2]   a[3]   a[4]   a[5] ....
i=1      +=0.5  +=1.0  +=0.5
i=2             +=0.5  +=1.0  +=0.5
i=3                    +=0.5  +=1.0  +=0.5
i=4                           +=0.5  +=1.0  +=0.5
  .
```

Notice that for a[2] through a[N-3] they are simply `a[i] = 0.5 + 1.0 + 0.5`.  You can replace the constants (0.5, 1.0, 0.5) with an array of values if you want.
Use this code.

```
void foo_v2(float *a, const int N) {
    a[0] += 0.5;
    a[1] += 0.5 + 1.0;
    a[N-1] += 0.5;
    a[N-2] += 1.0 + 0.5;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 2; i < N-2; i++) {
        a[i] += 0.5 + 1.0 + 0.5;
    }
}
```